# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted... or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT( m.pm_name ) 
FROM   prime_minister AS m, 
       prime_minister AS p 
WHERE  m.state_born IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY m.pm_name, 
          m.birth_yr 
HAVING m.birth_yr = (SELECT Min(p.birth_yr) 
                     FROM   prime_minister)
```

My problem is as follows:

the query is supposed to produce the first prime minister that was born in a state of Australia... hence the `WHERE m.state_born IS NOT NULL`

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It doesn't make sense to put the column names in brackets (and the distinct is useless anyway because you already apply a `group by`)

Answer (score 1):

Why to refer the external table in sub query? Write a simple sub query like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pm_name 
FROM prime_minister 
WHERE state_born IS NOT NULL 
AND birth_yr = (SELECT MIN(birth_yr) FROM prime_minister)
```

Comment: thanks, for that it is only returning a blank table now though

Comment: Actually, no need of `GROUP BY` also. Have a look at the updated query.

Comment: i just realised the problem... the MIN() will not work because the minimum birth year has a null in the state_born column... thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question completely. But I don't see the reason for a `group by` or `having` at all:

```
SELECT m.pm_name
FROM   prime_minister
WHERE  m.state_born IS NOT NULL 
AND    m.birth_yr = (SELECT Min(p.birth_yr) 
                     FROM   prime_minister p
                     WHERE  p.state_born IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT TOP 1 pm_name, MIN(birth_yr)
FROM   prime_minister
WHERE  birth_yr IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY pm_name
ORDER BY pm_name, MIN(birth_yr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to find the first prime minister born in each state:

```
select pm_name, state_born from prime_minister m
inner join 
(
    select min(birth_yr) birth_yr, state_born
    from prime_minister
    where state_born is not null
    group by state_born
)
t
on m.state_born = t.state_born and m.birth_yr = t.birth_yr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try option with EXISTS() operator

```
SELECT m.pm_name
FROM prime_minister AS m     
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM prime_minister p
              WHERE p.state_born IS NOT NULL
              HAVING MIN(p.birth_yr) = m.birth_yr
              ) AND m.state_born IS NOT NULL
```